# How can I display the date/time in multiple languages?

Tags: python, datetime, locale, python-babel

I would like to display the date and time (or either date or time, separately) in multiple languages.  Specifically English and Spanish, but perhaps in other languages in the future.

I've considered pythons time.strftime function in combination with locale.setlocal. I ruled this out after reading in the docs (http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html) that libraries should not call locale.setlocal, so I shouldn't just "flip flop" (change, and then restore) the locale settings in my library.

I've also considered the python library Babel, but I read in their docs (http://babel.edgewall.org/wiki/Documentation/0.9/dates.html) that date parsing "isn't properly implemented" which concerns me.  I do need date parsing abilities.  However, Babel can display the time using different locales.

A third [hybrid] option would be to use pythons datetime to parse the date, and then Babel to display the date in multiple languages/locales.  This is a little messy because strptime uses it's own format string syntax, while Babel uses LDML syntax for its format strings.

There may be other options.  The question again: What is the best way to display a date or time in multiple languages?

Comment: The 4th option I've considered is contributing to Babel so the parsing is more robust, then it would fit my needs perfectly.  In fairness I've not tested the existing parsing abilities, but the docs make them sound unreliable.

Comment: No what I mean is, why do you bother if you are making a library? Shouldn't the user call `locale.setlocal`?

Comment: The "user" should call setlocal, but it's bothersome to "flip flop" (change locale, get your date string, then set locale back) locale to get date strings from various locales.

Comment: Do you actually need the ability to parse dates in a locale-specific way (versus let's say from ISO format only), or do you only need locale-specific display?

Comment: I'd like to be able to parse dates/times from whatever format I receive them in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would maintain the translations as standard PO file using the **gettext** mechanism.
For each language you keep the translations in a dedicated file. You use the month and day names as **msgid** and keep the specific translations as **msgstr**.

http://docs.python.org/library/gettext.html